# how to merge some elements array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

example:

```
Array (
     [0] => 35
     [1] => -
     [2] => 59
     [3] => *
     [4] => 2
     [5] => /
     [6] => 27
     [7] => *
     [8] => 2 )
```

then calculated:

`59*2=118`

and the new array is:

```
 Array (
    [0] => 35
     [1] => -
     [2] => 118
     [3] => /
     [4] => 27
     [5] => *
     [6] => 2 )
```

this is my original source : 
`input ($_POST['numbers'])` is a string, LIKE:

`65*6/6+5-5`

```
class calculator {
    //property
    private $str='';
    private $len=0;
    private $ar_str=array();
    private $ar_design=array();
    private $ar_sum=array();
    private $ar_min=array();
    private $ar_mult=array();
    private $ar_divi=array();

//Method
public function __construct($str1=''){
    $this->str=$str1;
    $this->len=strlen($this->str);
    $this->ar_str=str_split($this->str);
    if($this->ar_str[0] == '+' ||
    $this->ar_str[0] == '-' ||
    $this->ar_str[0] == '*' ||
    $this->ar_str[0] == '/' ||
    $this->ar_str[$this->len-1] == '+' ||
    $this->ar_str[$this->len-1] == '-' ||
    $this->ar_str[$this->len-1] == '*' ||
    $this->ar_str[$this->len-1] == '/'
    ){
        exit("Syntax error!");
    }else if(!filter_var($this->ar_str[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
        exit("just use numbers and 4 operators!");
    }
    $this->ar_design[0]=$this->ar_str[0];
    //start for
    $j=1;
    for($i=1;$i<$this->len;$i++){
        if($this->ar_str[$i] == '+' || $this->ar_str[$i] == '-' || $this->ar_str[$i] == '*' || $this->ar_str[$i] == '/'){
            if($this->ar_str[$i-1] == '+' || $this->ar_str[$i-1] == '-' || $this->ar_str[$i-1] == '*' || $this->ar_str[$i-1] == '/'){
                exit("Syntax error!");
            }else{
                $this->ar_design[$j]=$this->ar_str[$i];
                $j++;
            }
        }else if(filter_var($this->ar_str[$i], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){
            if($this->ar_str[$i-1] == '+' || $this->ar_str[$i-1] == '-' || $this->ar_str[$i-1] == '*' || $this->ar_str[$i-1] == '/'){
                $this->ar_design[$j]=$this->ar_str[$i];
            }else{
                $j--;
                $this->ar_design[$j]=$this->ar_design[$j].$this->ar_str[$i];
            }
        $j++;
        }else{
            exit("just use numbers and 4 operators!");
        }
    }//end of for

    print_r($this->ar_design);//array this array should be calculate!!!!!
}//end construct
```

}

```
if(isset($_POST['numbers'])){
    $num_str=trim($_POST['numbers']);
    if($num_str!=''){
        $num_str = str_replace('`','+',$num_str);
        new calculator($num_str);
    }
}
```

i could find the answer:

```
$this->len_d=count($this->ar_design);
        $this->ar_cal[0]=$this->ar_design[0];
        $k=1;
        for($i=1;$i<$this->len_d;$i++){
            if($this->ar_design[$i] == '*'){
                $k--;
                $this->ar_cal[$k]=$this->ar_design[$i-1]*$this->ar_design[$i+1];
                $i++;
            }else{
                $this->ar_cal[$k]=$this->ar_design[$i];
            }
            $k++;
        }
        print_r($this->ar_cal);
```

Comment: What are you asking, exactly. be a little more specific ?

Comment: i try calculate this array and print the answer! this is a calculator that knows Priorities.

Comment: i dont draw calculating! i do these by php...

Comment: Consider implementing a simple [reverse polish calculator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). You only need a stack and to introduce the order of operations.

Comment: 59*2=118 ok. So what about 118/27=? and so on..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a loop and then executing it.

```
   $array=Array (35,'-',59,'*',2,'/',27,'*',2);
        foreach ($array as $value){
          $stringify.=$value;
        }
        echo 'Calculation looks like this: '.$stringify.'<br/>';

        function calculate( $math ){
            $calc = create_function("", "return (" .$math. ");" );
            return $calc();
        }   
        echo calculate($stringify);
```

could be imroved, for example by validating the input...

Working example: http://allanthya.net/arrcalc2.php

Comment: You can do this with PHP and never use `eval()`.

Comment: @nickb Please enlighten me, How? that's the solution i came up with anyhow.

Comment: It's simple, you have a list of defined numeric operators and use the built-in PHP operators to calculate the result of any operation by parsing the input expression.

Comment: You are correct, that's true

Comment: Considering the priority of the operators in calculating 35-118/27*2 answer is 32.814814814815 not 26.259259259259 !!!

Comment: it's wrong in his calculation not php's.

Comment: I wanted to be sure. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @user1281269 Try pasting the same into your calculator 
^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $array = array( 35, '-', 59, '*', 2, '/', 27, '*', 2 );
    print_r($array);
    echo "<p>";

    while ( true ) {
        $div = array_keys($array, '/');
        $mult = array_keys($array, '*');
        $add = array_keys($array, '+');
        $sub = array_keys($array, '-');

        if ( count($div) >= 1 ) {
            $index = $div[0];
            $op1 = $array[$index-1];
            $op2 = $array[$index+1];

            $array[$index] = $op1 / $op2;
            unset($array[$index-1]);
            unset($array[$index+1]);
            $array = array_values($array);

            continue;
        } else if ( count($mult) >= 1 ) {
            $index = $mult[0];
            $op1 = $array[$index-1];
            $op2 = $array[$index+1];

            $array[$index] = $op1 * $op2;
            unset($array[$index-1]);
            unset($array[$index+1]);
            $array = array_values($array);

            continue;
        } else if ( count($add) >= 1 ) {
            $index = $add[0];
            $op1 = $array[$index-1];
            $op2 = $array[$index+1];

            $array[$index] = $op1 + $op2;
            unset($array[$index-1]);
            unset($array[$index+1]);
            $array = array_values($array);

            continue;
        } else if ( count($sub) >= 1 ) {
            $index = $sub[0];
            $op1 = $array[$index-1];
            $op2 = $array[$index+1];

            $array[$index] = $op1 - $op2;
            unset($array[$index-1]);
            unset($array[$index+1]);
            $array = array_values($array);

            continue;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    print_r($array);
    echo "<p>";
?>
```

Heres the output of a print_r() after each iteration of the while loop so you can see it running through the divisions, multiplications, additions and subtractions one by one and thn modifying the array as it goes:

```
Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => - [2] => 59 [3] => * [4] => 2 [5] => / [6] => 27 [7] => * [8] => 2 )

Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => - [2] => 59 [3] => * [4] => 0.0740740740741 [5] => * [6] => 2 )

Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => - [2] => 4.37037037037 [3] => * [4] => 2 )

Array ( [0] => 35 [1] => - [2] => 8.74074074074 )

Array ( [0] => 26.2592592593 )
```

Comment: Solved! Check my revision :)

Comment: This assumes you want to do / then * then + then - - which is the bodmas rule. It doesnt take into account brackets or anything else, just /*+-

Comment: Considering the priority of the operators in calculating  35-118/27*2 answer is 32.814814814815 not 26.259259259259 !!!

Comment: Multiplication takes precedence over from division. Right?

Comment: Where do you get 118 from? Division happens first, so the order of operations is (2/27)*59*2 subtracted from 35. BODMAS! Division before Multiplication.

Comment: No problems, if it works for you, could you please accept the solution and vote it up ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not calculate as you go splitting the input into an array, and then just output the result?
Just as an example:

```
$input = "35-59*2/27*2";

if (preg_match('/[^-+*\/\\d]/', $input)) // simple checking
{
    echo "just use numbers and 4 operators!"; 
}
else
{
    $substraction = explode('-', $input);
    foreach ($substraction as $pos_s => $sub)
    {
        $addition = explode('+', $sub);
        foreach ($addition as $pos_a => $add)
        {
            $multiplication = explode('*', $add);
            foreach ($multiplication as $pos_m => $mult)
            {
                $division = explode('/', $mult);
                $d = $division[0];
                for ($i=1; $i < count($division);$i++)              
                    $d = $d / $division[$i];

                $multiplication[$pos_m] = $d;
            }
            $m = $multiplication[0];
            for ($i=1; $i < count($multiplication);$i++)                
                $m = $m * $multiplication[$i];

            $addition[$pos_a] = $m;
        }
        $a = $addition[0];
        for ($i=1; $i < count($addition);$i++)              
            $a = $a + $addition[$i];

        $substraction[$pos_s] = $a;
    }
    $result = $substraction[0];
    for ($i=1; $i < count($substraction);$i++)              
        $result = $result - $substraction[$i];
    echo $input . " = " . $result; 
}
```

prints

> 35-59*2/27*2 = 26.259259259259